# How to find and replace unique field name on mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 1.6 million documents in mongodb like this:

```
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57580c3f7e1a1469e772345b"),
        "https://www.....com/vr/s1812227" : {
            "suitability" : "children welcome",
            "details" : {
                "lookingCount" : 0,
                "photoUrl" : "https://www.....com/vr/s1812227/....",
                "partner" : null,
                 .........
                }
                .........
          }
    }

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57580c3f7e1a1469e772346d"),
        "https://www.....com/vr/s1812358" : {
            "suitability" : "children welcome",
            "details" : {
                "lookingCount" : 0,
                "photoUrl" : "https://www.....com/vr/s1812358/....",
                "partner" : null,
                 .........
                }
                .........
          }
    }

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57580c3f7e1a1469e772346d"),
        "https://www.....com/vr/s1812358/unite/125" : {
            "suitability" : "children welcome",
            "details" : {
                "lookingCount" : 0,
                "photoUrl" : "https://www.....com/vr/s1812358/....",
                "partner" : null,
                 .........
                }
                .........
          }
    }
```

I want like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("57580c3f7e1a1469e772345b"),
        "products" : {
            "suitability" : "children welcome",
            "details" : {
                "lookingCount" : 0,
                "photoUrl" : "https://www.....com/vr/s1812227/....",
                "partner" : null,
                 .........
                }
                .........
          }
    }
```

Edit content.... Thanks for your answer and interest in advance.

**UPDATE**
I'm trying this code but maximum 1200 documents insert to new collection. I have 1.5 million documents.

```
db.sourceColl.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    for (var k in doc) {
            if (k.match(/^https.*/) ) {
                db.sourceColl.find({ "_id": doc._id });
                db.getSiblingDB('targetdb')['targetColl'].insert({products: doc[k]});
            }
    }
});
```

After I'm try this and insert 20 documents to new collection. I'm so confused. how to rename and copy new collection all documents. **UPDATE2:** I use robomongo and I think there are limits in robomongo. This code works without problem in mongo shell. search, replace and copy new document.

```
var bulk = db.sourceColl.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.sourceColl.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    for (var k in doc) {
            if (k.match(/^https.*/) ) {
                print(k)
                bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id });
                db.getSiblingDB('targetDB')['targetColl'].insert({products: doc[k]});
                counter++;
            }
    }
    if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.sourceColl.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }

});
if ( counter % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Comment: You really don't want to have dynamic field's name in your collection. You should reconsider your schema design.

Comment: @user3100115 I think that's exactly what the OP is trying to fix. tabarly, it would be best if you added your attempt at a solution to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think I found the solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202418/mongodb-how-to-rename-a-field-using-regex?rq=1 I am trying. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are limits in robomongo. This code works fine in mongo shell. search, replace and copy new collection.

```
var bulk = db.sourceColl.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.sourceColl.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    for (var k in doc) {
            if (k.match(/^https.*/) ) {
                print(k)
                bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id });
                db.getSiblingDB('targetDB')['targetColl'].insert({products: doc[k]});
                counter++;
            }
    }
    if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.sourceColl.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }

});
if ( counter % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

I have modified this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204168/6446251